# Reference error: require is not defined (app.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, openshift, require

I have this line in my app.js file for node.js

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
```

Due to require not being defined, the javascript does not load on the webpage. I know that require is not in browsers, however the code worked when deployed on heroku and ibm bluemix, just not on openshift, which is what I am trying to run it with.

Any help is appreciated thank you!

Comment: heroku/bluemix may have been adding in a library that adds `require`, if openshift doesn't do that you will have to do it yourself.

Comment: Looked over that but found that the require command works in the other files, just not specifically in the app.js file.

Comment: You mean other client side files, or server side files?

Comment: Correction: actually require() is only in the app.js file. Also,t he css wasn't working either until I added self.app.use(express.static(__dirname)); in server.js. So it is possible that there's a missing library.